# How do I print a custom description of a Swift struct while debugging, and nothing else?

Tags: xcode, swift

Say I have a struct like this one:

```
struct MyStruct: CustomStringConvertible {
    let myInt: Int
    let myString: String

    var description: String {
        return "my int is \(myInt),\nand my string is \"\(myString)\""
    }
}
```

Printing a description from the code works fine.

```
let myStruct = MyStruct(myInt: 3, myString: "hello")
print(myStruct)
```

This results in

```
my int is 3,
and my string is "hello"
```

Problems arise when I want to print `myStruct`'s description from the debugger. `po myStruct` results in

```
▿ my int is 3,
and my string is "hello"
  - myInt : 3
  - myString : "hello"
```

Explicitly printing out its description doesn't help either, as `po myStruct.description` results in

```
"my int is 3,\nand my string is \"hello\""
```

I thought it might have to do with `CustomDebugStringConvertible`, so I added this code:

```
extension MyStruct: CustomDebugStringConvertible {
    var debugDescription: String {
        return description
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't change any of the outcomes at all.

Is there a way to just have

```
my int is 3,
and my string is "hello"
```

printed from the command line while debugging?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(lldb) expression print(myStruct)
my int is 3,
and my string is "hello"
```

you can defined your own 'command'

```
(lldb) help command
The following subcommands are supported:

      alias   -- Allow users to define their own debugger command
                 abbreviations.  This command takes 'raw' input (no need to
                 quote stuff).
      delete  -- Allow the user to delete user-defined regular expression,
                 python or multi-word commands.
      history -- Dump the history of commands in this session.
      regex   -- Allow the user to create a regular expression command.
      script  -- A set of commands for managing or customizing script commands.
      source  -- Read in debugger commands from the file <filename> and execute
                 them.
      unalias -- Allow the user to remove/delete a user-defined command
                 abbreviation.
```

Comment: Thanks! I ended up using `command regex expr 's/(.+)/expression print(%1)/'`.